# Interrupt and delay problems on Attiny 85

Tags: arduino-ide, interrupt, attiny

I wrote this code and uploaded it to attiny85:

```
 int hours = 2;
 int minutes = 4;
 static int MINUTES_COUNT_BIT = 5;
 static int HOURS_COUNT_BIT = 3;
 #define button 2
void setup() {
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button,INPUT);

  attachInterrupt(0,pin_ISR,CHANGE);



}

void loop() {

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


}

void pin_ISR(){
    if(digitalRead(button)==LOW){
      for(int i = HOURS_COUNT_BIT;i>=0;i--){
      byte act_bit = bitRead(hours,i);

      switch(act_bit){
        case 0:
          digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
          delay(1000);
          digitalWrite(3,LOW);
          delay(1000);
          break;
        case 1:
          digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
          delay(1000);
          digitalWrite(4,LOW);
          delay(1000);

          break;
        }

    }
  }

  }
```

When I click button it lights up LEDs but it is so much faster than 500 milliseconds it looks like that:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByeWvrEgy2gRNUp3MDNxQTAxd2c
Please help

Comment: Maybe you did not Burn Bootloader with the same MHz setting as you uploaded the Sketch.

Comment: Delay in an ISR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

- Arduino `delay()` is relying on `millis()`.
- The `millis()` function is  updated by timer `ISR`.
- `ISR` handler blocks all other ISRs by disabling global interrupts.
- No update for `millis` results into deadlock in `delay` if you use it in another `ISR`

And recommendation for ISRs? **Do it as short as possible!** Set some volatile flag and do the action later outside of ISR.